# In google maps react native, loading maps, draw polyline or markers its all free or paid?

Tags: react-native

In google maps react native, loading maps, draw polyline or markers its all free or paid. I want to know some clarification. I have to use to for android and ios both.Please tell me this thing as soon as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, will show you the Monthly pay, no pay needed for less than 100K users:

[image: Google Map]

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps